# can every bare 'except' be converted to something better?

Tags: python

I am struggling with the following code. My goal is to check if the `arg` which is a string can be executed deciding the different return value.

```py
    def process(arg):
        try:
            return eval(arg)
        except:
            return arg
```

Pycharm tells me not to use *bare 'except'* but I cannot find a good alternative. And I am also wondering if this is another choice?

Comment: You could catch a `BaseException`, which will be identical to your existing code, but it doesn't change the fact that this smells.

Comment: As an aside, executing arbitrary user input is pretty dangerous. If you want to catch all exceptions then the best practice is to use `except Exception:`. This will catch all the stuff you want to while still allowing stuff like "Ctrl-C" to exit your program. Also see https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#base-classes

Comment: A bare `except` catches *all* exceptions, which means an instance of `BaseException`. You can then divide the subclass of `BaseException` into two groups: `Exception` (which is the base class of all "regular" exceptions, and the rest (`SystemExit`, `StopIteration`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, etc) which act more as flow-control primitives than true exceptions. You virtually *never* want to catch any instances of the second group, so you should use at a minimum, `except Exception`. Strive, however, to catch only the most specific exception you *need* to catch.

Comment: @chepner thanks, it is really a good explanation. I have ever been so clear about the errors till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use `except` then you catch everything that inherits from BaseException, including things like KeyboardInterrupt. This is probably not what you intend. Chances are good that you will end up masking error conditions that you actually wanted to know about.

[This page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) discusses a potentially good use of catching all exceptions - to log the exception (e.g. at the top level of a program or module) and immediately re-raise it. That bit about re-raising it is important because it means you're not hiding the error when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably wanting you to catch and handle a specific type of exception.

Something like:

```
def process(arg):
        try:
            with open (arg) as myFile:
                return myFile.read()
        except IOError as e:
            # The file could not be read, some other IO related error
            print ("the file could not be read")
            raise e
```

That way you know what type of error it is and the nature of it, and can handle it appropriately rather than catching every error and assuming the one you catch is of a certain type, or checking the type at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> "My goal is to check if the arg which is a string can be executed"

If you only want to check if it can be executed use `compile` it will raise `SyntaxError` if it can’t be.

```
try:
    compile(arg)
except SyntaxError:
    return False
return True
```

Otherwise use `Exception` as a more default exception.

```
try:
    return eval(arg)
except Exception:
    return arg
```

You can `except` different exceptions and decide what to return based on the exception too.